# Cannot install any packages using pip

Tags: python, pip

Unsure where to begin on this as i've searched for a while and could not find any one with a similar issue nor any documentation (Please link if you do find one similar).

I am unable to install any python packages using pip as I get the same error message below for each package.
These timeouts even occur when trying to run py get-pip.py

> I have already tried:
>
> - Removing computer from work domain
> - Connecting via hotspot
> - Completely uninstalling and reinstalling python3.10, pip, pycharm and anything else relating to python
> - Ensuring my IP wasn't blacklisted from pypi
> - Checking pip documentation for any similar errors

I know this is a very broad question so if anyone has anything else to check it would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know if you need any other details like OS

```
message `WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/requests/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.`
```

Comment: Have you tried using `py -m ensurepip --upgrade` (assuming you are on windows)? Besides that, `pip` should be already installed with you `python`-installation as it's included in most cases.

Comment: @Mime Just tried this and gave me two 'Requirement already satisfied' messages. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Can you try if `pip install request -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.douban.com` works? If that works, than there seem something wrong with the TLS-Certificate of `pypi` on your side, as `pypi` only accepts `https` (as it should be). Possible solution from https://bytemeta.vip/repo/pypa/pip/issues/10677

Comment: @Mime thankyou so much, that seemed to work. I'll have a look into the TLS-certificate as you said

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue while disconnected the VPN. One more thing, go to computer network connection and find proxy setting and turn off proxy setting and set the internet connection with automatic default.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the suggestion. I've just tried both changes and still isnt working

Answer (score 0):

[Temporary workaround by @Mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412368/cannot-install-any-packages-using-pip/73412680#comment129644589_73412368):

> Can you try if `pip install request -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple --trusted-host pypi.douban.com` works? If that works, than there seem something wrong with the TLS-Certificate of `pypi` on your side, as `pypi` only accepts `https` (as it should be). Possible solution from https://bytemeta.vip/repo/pypa/pip/issues/10677

Will update when TLS-Certificate issue is resolved